# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**When I run the app Its working but when I run it again I get this error. This is a quiz game.**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.fillintheblank, PID: 32237
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
> at com.example.fillintheblank.filldisQuizActivity.SetNewQuestion(filldisQuizActivity.java:264)
> at com.example.fillintheblank.filldisQuizActivity.access$400(filldisQuizActivity.java:33)
> at com.example.fillintheblank.filldisQuizActivity$3$3.run(filldisQuizActivity.java:362)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:230)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)

heres my code

> 

```
private void SetNewQuestion(){

    qid++;

    txtTotalQuesText.setText(qid + "/" + sizeofQuiz);

    currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
    enableOptions();
    displayButtons();
    updateQueAnsOptions();
}
```

this is the size of my quiz

> int qid = 1;  int sizeofQuiz = 5; // total size of Quiz

Comment: All we can say with what little information you have given is that you are incorrectly accessing an index of an array somewhere

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException` you can check if you are in the index range of the list:

```
private void SetNewQuestion() {

    qid++;

    txtTotalQuesText.setText(qid + "/" + sizeofQuiz);

    if (qid < list.size()) {
        currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
    }
    enableOptions();
    displayButtons();
    updateQueAnsOptions();
}
```

Indexes in **Java** are starting from 0. So if you have a list of size 5, you can get elements by using indexes 0..4.

In your case the index was 5 and the size as well, but the maximum index for the list of 5 elements is 4.

Comment: This is a possible solution.  But most likely they shouldn't call this function if qid would be out of range.  And qid increasing as a side effect is a giant code smell, this should probably be rewritten to pass in qid as a parameter, and the code that calls this should ensure qid never goes out of range.